# XOR Encryption in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, xor

I am trying to implement a simple XOR Encryption using a number, of type `long`. Unfortunately, some of the numbers return some symbols that decrypting them gives a whole different text than the one entered.

For example, encrypting a text `'hello world'` with the key `'5105105105'` returns this `'��'`. To decrypt it back with the same key, it returns this `'>nl wor>nl'`. I am not sure why is it doing this.

This is my code:

```
string encDec(string str, long key) {
    string output = str;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        output[i] = str[i] ^ key;

    return output;
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please create a [mre].

Comment: Why not do some debugging and print out the intermediate values in the loop?  Maybe by seeing the integer value, it will give you an indication of what the error is.  Seeing a bunch of bloops and beeps in a string doesn't give you (or us) any information.

Comment: Related to your problem, the biggest issue I see will be the chance where a key and value element host the same value. Ask yourself, "what does `a ^ a` always result in, and how well will that play in what appears to be a string ? At a minimum the result of this "encryption" should be a byte-vector; not a string.

Comment: @WhozCraig yes the result isn't a character string, but it can fit into a `std::string` which is just a specialized type of vector of `char` elements.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at: `output[i] = str[i] ^ key;`

What this does is that it first retrieves a character from the string `str` at index `i`. A character in `std::string` is equivalent to an 8 bit byte.

Then this byte is being coaxed into a `long` using an *implicit widening conversion* to match the left `key`.

After that all the bits are XOR'ed with the key, performing the "encryption". I've put this in quotes because repeated use of the key with a XOR cipher is of course not secure.

Finally an implicit narrowing conversion is used to assign this long value to the char array again.

In other words, you can see this as performing: `output[i] = (char) ((long) str[i] ^ key;` if you make the conversions explicit. Note that many bits are first XOR'ed, and then thrown away during the narrowing conversion; probably not what you want as those key bits are basically ignored.

---

Of course if you XOR with random bits then what you get in return is a random binary pattern. This kind of pattern may not consist of printable characters. You either have to store or send those as binary values, or you must first convert them back to printable text. Usually we do that using hex or base 64 encoding of the bytes.

Modern cryptography operates on bits and bytes. Classical ciphers such as Caesar and Vigenere ciphers do operate on text and gave text as output. In the end, XOR is an operation on bits, not on characters of a text.

Comment: Thank you @Maarten for the comprehensive explanation of the whole process.